# How to force input from tty

Tags: c, input, tty

I'd like to write a program which reads user input only from tty, instead of redirected stdin pipes, like **passwd** and **ssh** do. Is there any approach?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try opening `/dev/tty` directly. That's the only way I know for sure that you can bypass the `stdin` redirection.

`/dev/tty` is usually a symbolic link to your *actual* tty device, which may be `/dev/console` or `/dev/tty24` or pretty much anything you want, depending on the weird and wonderful way your system may be set up. The `tty` command should be able to tell you which one it is (as will listing the symbolic link itself with `ls -al /dev/tty`).

But as long as you open `dev/tty` for input, it should get the input from your terminal rather than the standard input stream, which may have been redirected.

Comment: /dev/tty is not really a symbolic link, but it's a real device file which the kernel uses to mean the controlling terminal for the process which is trying to use it.  The controlling terminal is what you'd want for things like passwords and less keystrokes.

Comment: Maybe that's a Linux thing, @nategoose. I seem to remember it showing up as "tty -> ttyd9" (a symbolic link) in some UNIXes and indeed using a nasty trick like temorarily replacing /dev/tty with a real file so that programs using the fopen(/dev/tty) method that I suggest would instead read my file (for automation and, of course, needed root privs).

Answer (score 1):

You can try isatty(man 3 isatty) in conjunction with fileno():

```
   #include <unistd.h>

   int isatty(int fd);
```